# How do Python commands, and any other commands, get automatically set up in terminal?

Tags: terminal

I was trying to set up a platform that used pip and I realized I had to install it using 'sudo easy_install'. I think easy_install is a python-enabled command that was set up in terminal after I installed Python.

How does it work that after you install something like Python, a command like easy_install is automatically activated with-in terminal that can call what easy_install does? Is there some sort of active list of commands that is updated for all terminal executions by programs that are installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the places that the terminal will search for programs are in the `PATH` variable. To see which directories are in your path variable you can run the following in your terminal: `echo $PATH`. Note that paths are colon separated on most UNIX-based systems. As such, all programs contained in directories that are in the `PATH` variable are ones that can be run without specifying a relative/absolute path to them.